# plot between two predictors X1 and X2:

Tags: r, correlation, linear-model, intercept

Given the following scatter plot between two predictors $X_1$ and $X_2$:

[image]

Is there a way to get the number of parameters of a linear model like that? model `<- lm(Y~X1+X2)` I would like to get the number 3 somehow (intercept + $X_1$ + $X_2$). I looked for something like this in the structures that lm, `summary(model)` and `anova(model)` return, but I didn't figure it out. In case I don't get an answer, I'll stick on `dim(model.matrix(model))`[2]

I was thinking that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are correlated. Collinearity will reduce the accuracy of the estimates of the regression coefficients

Maybe the The importance of either $X_1$ or $X_2$ variable may be masked due to the presence of collinearity?

Though they both could be correct.

Comment: The answer is both. Both answers are correct.

yes.  X1 and X2 are correlated. Collinearity will reduce the accuracy of the estimates of the regression coefficients.

   
Yes. The importance of either X1 or X2 variable may be masked due to the presence of collinearity.

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE! If you feel that you know the answer, you're allowed to answer your own question using the Answer box below your post. This also lets you gain reputation points for both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is both. Both answers are correct. yes. X1 and X2 are correlated. Collinearity will reduce the accuracy of the estimates of the regression coefficients. Yes. The importance of either X1 or X2 variable may be masked due to the presence of collinearity.